# Is the ball ratio theorem for Radon Nikodym derivative known for general metric spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

Given two non-negative Borel measures $\mu$, $\nu$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, that are finite on compact sets, such that $\nu<<\mu$, it is well known that

$$\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}(x)= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{\nu(B_\epsilon(x))}{\mu(B_\epsilon(x))}$$

holds $\mu$ a.e., where $B_\epsilon(x)$ is the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Can this be generalized to arbitrary metric spaces, or even Banach spaces?

Comment: Well, you should at the very least assume that the measures are locally finite. If the space is not locally compact, then your hypothesis is way too weak.

Comment: What about probability measures on Banach spaces though? I am particularly interested in sigma algebra generated by cylindrical sets.